# Got stuck on using prepare() and bindvalue() in c++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql

I've written a SQL query based on Qt assistant and it says that you can use the `prepare()` method instead of `exec()` then you can pass your parameter by the help of two methods called :
`bindvalue()` and `addbindvalue()`

Here is an snippet code of my problem :

```
Query->prepare("SELECT ID , Row , Col FROM sometable WHERE Row = :row AND Col = :col");
Query->bindValue(":row" , __Row);
Query->bindValue(":col" ,__Col);
Query->exec();
qDebug("%s" , Query->executedQuery().toStdString().c_str());
```

output :

> SELECT ID , Row , Col FROM sometable WHERE Row = ? AND Col = ?

and also I've used another suggested way :

```
Query->prepare("SELECT ID , Row , Col FROM sometable WHERE Row = :row AND Col = :col");
Query->addBindValue(0 , __Row);
Query->addBindValue(1 ,__Col);
Query->exec();
qDebug("%s" , Query->executedQuery().toStdString().c_str());
```

output :

> SELECT ID , Row , Col FROM sometable WHERE Row = ? AND Col = ?

but when I use `exec()` normally it works perfectly and will replace the corresponding values instead of "?".

is there any explanation about that? or should I use the ordinary exec()?

Comment: Small unrelated comment, instead of `qDebug("%s",str.toStdString().c_str())`, do `qDebug() << str`.

Answer (score 5):

Is the exec() call failing ?
Because it may just be ok what you're seeing, as ,depending on which sql server you're using, the binding could be done by the server ( e.g. Oracle ).
According to Qt docs, executedQuery: "In most cases this function returns the same string as lastQuery(). ***If a prepared query with placeholders is executed on a DBMS that does not support it, the preparation of this query is emulated***". So, I guess, if the server supports binding values the preparation won't be emulated so you'd just see the query without the placeholders being replaced by real values.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess but from http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qsqlquery.html I read the following:

> **Warning**: You must load the SQL driver and open the connection before a QSqlQuery is created. Also, the connection must remain open while the query exists; otherwise, the behavior of QSqlQuery is undefined.

Is the connection open in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to how your query constructed with prepared statements:

```
qDebug("%s" , Query.lastQuery().toStdString().c_str());
```